# default value for Future method parameter

Tags: scala

Is there a way to provide default value for a method parameter that is of type `Future`?

we can do:

```
def myMethod(test: String = "") {...}
```

but what if we have a Future

```
def myMethod(test: Future[List[Color]]) {...} //How can I set default for this?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Future[A]` will contain either

- Successful result of type `A`
- Failed result of type throwable

Example:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> val success = Future.successful("some data")
success: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = Future(Success(some data))

scala> val failed = Future.failed(throw new Exception("failed"))
java.lang.Exception: failed
  ... 30 elided
```

Which means you can assign default value in your example as `Future.successful`,

```
def myMethod(test: Future[List[Color]] = Future.successful(List.empty[Color])) {...}
```

Example:

```
scala> implicit val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3@3c8802cf[Running, parallelism = 8, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]

scala> def addLoyaltyPoints(previousLoyalty: Future[Int] = Future.successful(0)): Future[Int] = previousLoyalty.map(_ + 2)
addLoyaltyPoints: (previousLoyalty: scala.concurrent.Future[Int])scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> addLoyaltyPoints()
res16: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> res16
res17: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Success(2))
```

It is always good practice in codebase to mark already computed result as `Future.successful(a)` instead of `Future(a)` because `Future(a)` will run on a thread. It does not make sense to assign a thread for pre-computed result.

Comment: thanks -  is it a good idea to put a `Future` in a `case` class? On that note - I have another question around getting elements from Future and passing them onto another method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798622/how-to-put-contents-of-stream-into-a-val would love your help there.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to have `Future[A]` to `case class` because `case class` represent the state. Instead you can have `Future[CaseClass]`